# How to convolve two blobs in caffe

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, convolution

In caffe, the `convolution` layer takes one bottom blob, and convolves it with learned filters (which are initialized using the weight type - "Xavier", "MSRA" etc.). However, my question is whether we can simply convolve two bottom blobs and produce a top blob. What would be the most elegant way of doing this? The purpose of this is: one of the bottom blob will be `data` and the other one will be a dynamic filter (changing depending on the `data`) produced by previous layers (I am trying to implement [dynamic convolution](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~wolf/papers/dynconv.pdf)).

**My attempt:**

One way which came to my mind was to modify the `filler.hpp` and assign a bottom blob as a `filler` matrix itself (instead of "Xavier", "MSRA" etc.). Then I thought the convolution layer would pick up from there. We can set `lr = 0` to indicate that the weight initialized by our custom filler should not be changed. However, after I looked at the source code, I still don't know how to do it. On the other hand, I don't want to break the workflow of caffe. I still want conv layers to function normally, if I want them to.

Obviously a more tedious way is to use a combination of `Slice`, `tile` and/or `Scale` layer to literally implement convolution. I think it would work, but it will turn out to be messy. Any other thoughts?

**Edit 1:**

I wrote a new layer by modifying the convolution layer of caffe. In particular, in `src/caffe/layers/conv_layer.cpp`, on line 27, it takes the weight defined by the `filler` and convolves it with the bottom blob. So instead of populating that blob from the `filler`, I modified the layer such that it now takes two bottoms. One of the bottom directly gets assigned to the filler. Now I had to make some other changes such as:

1. `weight` blob has the same value for all the samples. Here it will have a different value for different samples. So I changed line 32 from:

```cpp
this->forward_cpu_gemm(
    bottom_data + n * this->bottom_dim_, 
    weight, 
    top_data + n * this->top_dim_);
```

to:

```cpp
this->forward_cpu_gemm(
    bottom_data + n * bottom[1]->count(1),
    bottom[0]->cpu_data() + n * bottom[0]->count(1), 
    top_data + n * this->top_dim_);
```

To make things easier, I assumed that there is no bias term involved, stride is always 1, padding can always be 0, group will always be 1 etc. However, when I tested the forward pass, it gave me some weird answer (with a simple convolution kernel = `np.ones((1,1,3,3))`. The learning rates were set to zero for this kernel so that it doesn't change. However, I can't get a right answer. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Please do not propose solutions using existing layers such as `Slice, Eltwise, Crop`. I have already implemented - it works - but it is unbelievably complex and memory inefficient.

Comment: I read it "How to convince two blonds in caffe" :\

Comment: @Elazar so that's why you down-voted? (just kidding) :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are on the right way as a whole.

For the "weird" convolution results, I guess the bug most possibly is:

Consider 2D convolution

and suppose `bottom[1]`'s shape is `(num, channels, height, width)`,

since convolution in `caffe` is performed as a multiplication of 2 matrix, `weight`(representing convolution kernels) and `col_buffer`(reorganized from data to be convolved), and `weight` is of `num_out` rows and `channels / this->group_ * kernel_h * kernel_w` columns, `col_buffer` is of `channels / this->group_ * kernel_h * kernel_w` rows and `height_out * width_out` columns, so as a `weight` blob of dynamic convolution layer, `bottom[0]`'s shape should better be `(num, num_out, channels/group, kernel_h, kernel_w)` to satisfy

```
bottom[0]->count(1) == num_out * channels / this->group_ * kernel_h * kernel_w
```

, in which `num_out` is the number of the dynamic convolution layer's output feature maps.

That means, to make the convolution function

```
this->forward_cpu_gemm(bottom_data + n * bottom[1]->count(1) 
                     , bottom[0]->cpu_data() + n * bottom[0]->count(1)
                     , top_data + n * this->top_dim_);
```

work properly, you must make sure that

```
bottom[0]->shape(0) == bottom[1]->shape(0) == num
bottom[0]->count(1) == num_out * channels / this->group_ * kernel_h * kernel_w
```

**So most possibly the simple convolution kernel of 4-dimension `np.ones((1,1,3,3))` you used may not satify the above condition and result in the wrong convolution results**.

Hope it's clear and will help you.

**########## Update 1, Oct 10th,2016,Beijing time ##########**

I add a dynamic convolution layer [**here**](https://github.com/knsong/caffe-mt/tree/master) but with no unit test yet. This layer doesn't break the workflow of caffe and only change some private members of BaseConvolution class to be protected.

The files involved are:

```
include/caffe/layers/dyn_conv_layer.hpp,base_conv_layer.hpp
src/caffe/layers/dyn_conv_layer.cpp(cu)
```

It grows almost the same with the convolution layer in `caffe`, and the differences mainly are:

1. Override the function `LayerSetUp()` to initialize `this->kernel_dim_`, `this->weight_offset_` etc properly for convolution and ignore initializing `this->blobs_` used by Convolution layer routinely to contain weight and bias;
2. Override the function `Reshape()` to check that the `bottom[1]` as a kernel container has proper shape for convolution.

Because I have no time to test it, there may be bugs and I will be very glad to see your feedbacks.

**########## Update 2, Oct 12th,2016,Beijing time ##########**

I updated test case for [**dynamic convolution**](https://github.com/knsong/caffe-mt/tree/master) just now. The involved file is `src/caffe/test/test_dyn_convolution_layer.cpp`. It seems to work fine, but maybe need more thorough tests.

You can build this caffe by `cd $CAFFE_ROOT/build && ccmake ..`, `cmake -DBUILD_only_tests="dyn_convolution_layer" ..` and `make runtest` to check it.

Comment: I will try this out in the next 3-4 days and let you know the outcome. Thanks!

Comment: You should pay much attention to function BaseConvolutionLayer<Dtype>::LayerSetUp(), because many variables used in forward_cpu_gemm() are initialized there. @ParagS.Chandakkar

Comment: I suppose when you have two bottom blobs, you can ignore the convolution parameters setting kernel size and number of filters. These values should be deduced from the "weights" blob. And you might also consider third input blob for the bias term...

Comment: Good point. And to deduce the kernel shape, we should explicitly set each dimension of the "weights" blob's shape. Compared with this, setting kernel size only requires that the "weights" blob(here, bottom[0])'s shape satisfies 'bottom[0]->count(1) == num_out * channels / this->group_ * kernel_h * kernel_w'. @Shai

Comment: @DaleSong Can you award bounty after its expired? I was out of town and I want to award full bounty (150) to you. I have not tried the solution but I appreciate your efforts.